# Android Get locale for current app but not the device default locale

Tags: android, locale

How to get current App's language, but not the device language?

I've done research online, and found most of responses are using: `Locale.getDefault()` and `getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales()`, which I don't think work for my situation.

For example, I set Android device language to "French (Belgium)" (language tag: fr-be) and my app only supports "fr, fr-CA, fr-CH". After installing the app, it shows in French, but these two functions both return "fr-be":

```
Locale.getDefault() -> fr-be
fragment.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0) -> fr-be
```

I'm so confused since my app doesn't support fr-be, but it does show in (some kind of)French. So how can I get what my app is using right now? It should be something from "fr, fr-CA or fr-CH".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How to get current App's language, but not the device language?

An app does not have a language. Hence, there is no "current App's language".

> I'm so confused since my app doesn't support fr-be

An app does not "support" a language.

An app has string resources. Those string resources might include translations for multiple languages. Each string resource has its own set of translations in its own set of languages. So, one of your own string resources might only have translations for fr, fr-CA or fr-CH, but a string resource that you get from libraries might have translations for different sets of languages.

> So how can I get what my app is using right now?

Your app is not using anything.

What Android uses as the translation for a string resource is determined at runtime for that individual string resource, at the time it is requested. It is conceivable that for 100 different string resources that 100 different language choices get made, based on the available translations in the app and the user's device-level language settings.

> It should be something from "fr, fr-CA or fr-CH"

For any given string resource, it *might* be from one of those. It might be from `fr-BE`, if the string resource happens to come from a library that happens to offer a `fr-BE` translation. It might be from the default `res/values/` source set, if the string resource happens to not have a better translation available.

But the key is that the language choice is made *for each individual string resource*, not for an entire app.